# Is it possible to execute a python script from a bash login shell with a one-line command from a non-login shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a use case where I need to execute a Python script I'm working on from a login shell due to a dependency on values sourced from /etc/profile.d/. There's several combinations I've tried, but I seem to run into one issue or another.

This is nested in another automated process that's running in a non-login shell so I'm looking for a one-line command to get this to work.

Does anyone know of a one-line command to get this to work?

For example, I tried the following, but it failed with the "cannot execute binary file" error:

```
bash --login python my_python_script.py
/usr/bin/python: /usr/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

I've also tried a few other combinations with and without the shebang. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `-c` there before the command and then you need to quote the command as a single argument.

```
bash --login -c 'python my_python_script.py'
```

If the shell also needs to be an interactive shell then the `-i` option needs to be used there also.

```
bash --login -i -c 'python my_python_script.py'
```

Comment: Then it won't be an interactive shell.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That's true. An interactive shell was not listed as a requirement. Should one be required the `-i` option can force that the way `--login` was forcing a login shell.